# Handling time using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, time

I have a table with a `date` and `time` field. I'm having difficulty understanding how I deal with this, partially as I don't understand how time can be converted to a number. I made a table using the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE tracking.time_record
(
  date date, 
  "time" time without time zone,
  id character(100)
)
```

An example of my data is as follows:

```
"2012-04-18" | "18:33:19.612" | "2342342384"
```

How can I run a query such that I can examine all of the `id` values that have a time value `> 10 pm` on a certain day, for example?

I realize that as my time is stored in a character type  variable so something like this does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM tracking.time_record 
WHERE "time" > "04:33:38.884" AND date > "2012-04-18"
```

(This is my first exploration of time/date tracking - I should probably have chosen different column names)

Comment: Why not combine the date + time into a timestamp with/without timezone? It will make comparisons easier, an you can always extract the relevant parts if you want them.

Comment: That's a good point. Now that I am getting a better understanding of how timestamps work I will do that in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither of the answers so far captures your actual problem(s).

While an explicit cast to the appropriate type certainly doesn't hurt, it is *not necessary*. PostgreSQL coerces a string literal to the appropriate type automatically.

Your problems stem from basic syntax errors:
**Double quotes** are for **identifiers**: `"MyColumn"` - and only necessary for otherwise illegal identifiers (mixed case, reserved word, ..) which should be avoided to begin with.
**Single quotes** are for **values**: `'string literal'`.

You might be interested in the well written chapters on [**identifiers**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) and [**constants**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) of the PostgreSQL manual.

While we are at it, *never* use `date` or `time` as column names. Both are [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in every SQL standard and type names in PostgreSQL. This will lead to confusing code and error messages.

I would recommend to just use a single `timestamp` column instead of separate `date` and `time`:
And you almost certainly don't want `character(100)` as data type, *ever* - especially not for an `id` column. This blank-padded type is basically only there for historic reasons. Consider `text` or `varchar` instead:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

Could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   tbl_id text CHECK(length(id) <= 100)
 , ts timestamp
);
```

Cast to `time` or `date` where you only need these components, it's short and cheap:

```
SELECT ts::time AS the_time, ts::date AS the_date FROM tbl;
```

Use [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) or [`extract()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) for more specific needs.
To query for ... *id values that have a time value > 10 pm on a certain day*:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  ts::time > '22:00'
AND    ts::date = '2012-04-18';
```

Or, for any continuous time period:

```
...
WHERE  ts > '2012-04-18 22:00'::timestamp
AND    ts < '2012-04-19 00:00'::timestamp;
```

The second form can use a plain index on `ts` better and will be faster in such cases for big tables.

More about `timestamp` handling in PostgreSQL:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Comment: BTW, I doubt you actually want `character(100)` for your `id`. This blank-padded type is basically only there for historic reasons. Consider [`text` or `varchar`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [date_part](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html) function to get the hour

```
select id 
from tracking.time_record
where date_part('hour', time) >= 22
  and date = '2012-04-18'
```

The >= 22 instead of > 22 it's to catch intervals between 10pm and 11pm. This also catches 10:00:00pm. but its't hard to adapt the query to catch the right intervals

You have a working example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/92d52/1).

Comment: `date_part()` is not necessary, either. `"time" > '22:00'` would do.

Answer (score 3):

comparing time and date values should work fine in postgresql, just make sure you convert your strings to the appropriate types:

```
SELECT * FROM tracking.time_record 
WHERE "time" > time '04:33:38.884' AND "date" > date '2012-04-18'
```

Comment: Note that this will find records from 2012-04-18 onwards after 4:33am. (so nothing before that day and also nothing from before 4:33am on any day). What you probably want is a timestamp column.

Comment: Casting (while no harm) is not necessary in this situation. Postgres coerces a string literal to the matching type automatically here. Syntax errors are the problem.

Comment: You are right. I would still recommend the cast. Is it comparing strings or dates or something else? You really can't tell without looking at the table specification.