# Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, postgresql-performance

According to the [PostgreSQL Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html.), they support 3 data-types for character data:

```
character varying(n), varchar(n)  variable-length with limit
character(n), char(n)             fixed-length, blank padded
text                              variable unlimited length
```

In my application, I came across few unpleasant scenarios where insert/update queries failed as the desired text to be inserted exceeded the `varchar(n)` or `char(n)` limit.

For such cases, changing the data type of such columns to `text` sufficed.

My questions are:

- If we generalize and change the data type of every character storing column to `text`, is there any downside in terms of performance/memory?
- If a column with data type `text` stores 10 or less characters every time, should I go for `text` or `varchar(10)`?
- If I go for `text` what's the downside?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/23988406/398670

Answer (score 72):

Generally, there is **no** downside to using [**`text`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-TABLE) in terms of performance/memory. On the contrary: `text` is the optimum. Other types have more or less relevant downsides. `text` is literally the ["preferred" type among string types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html) in the Postgres type system, which can affect function or operator type resolution.

In particular, [**never** use <strike>**`char(n)`**</strike>](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29) (alias for [<strike>`character(n)`</strike>](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-TABLE)), unless you know what you are doing. `char` or `character` are just short for `character(1)`, so all the same. The internal name is `bpchar` (stands fore "blank-padded character"). The type is only there for compatibility with old code and standards. It makes very little sense nowadays, wastes memory and is likely to cause trouble:

- [Compare varchar with char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333196/compare-varchar-with-char/17333258#17333258)
- [String field length in Postgres SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988406/string-field-length-in-postgres-sql/23988687#23988687)

You can use [**`varchar(n)`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-TABLE) with length modifier (alias for `character varying(n)`). But [<strike>`varchar(255)`</strike> typically indicates a misunderstanding](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_varchar.28n.29_by_default) carried over from other RDBMS where it might be a local optimum for performance. In Postgres, the length modifier `(255)` has no special meaning and rarely makes sense.

- [Should I add an arbitrary length limit to VARCHAR columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21496/3684)

Older versions caused various problems when trying to change the length modifier of `varchar(n)` later. Most of those have been alleviated in modern Postgres, but `text` or [**`varchar`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-TABLE) (alias for `character varying`) without length specifier (and a [`CHECK` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) instead) never had any of these issues.

A `CHECK` constraint is just as fast and less likely to cause troubles with depending views, functions, FK constraints etc. which depend on the column type. And it can do more than just enforce a maximum character length - anything you can put into a boolean expression. See:

- [Change PostgreSQL columns used in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524873/change-postgresql-columns-used-in-views/8527792#8527792)

Finally, there is also [**`"char"`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-SPECIAL-TABLE) (with double-quotes): a 1-byte data type for a single ASCII letter used as cheap internal enumeration type.

I rarely use anything but `text` for character data in Postgres.

Comment: As of PG 9.2, `varchar(n)` constraint can be increased/removed without a table rewrite. If you don't want to add SQL constraints directly, it's just easier with an ORM like Django that takes care of length constrained field by mapping them to `varchar(n)`. Is there any other reason to prefer `text` over `varchar(n)` other than the above issue that's addressed in 9.2? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/release-9-2.html

Comment: @buffer: Good point, important update. Postgres 9.2 brought major improvements removing the need for table rewrites when changing the length specifier. But `text` with `CHECK` constraints is still more versatile, more so with the introduction of [`NOT VALID` constraints](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75613/disable-all-constraints-and-table-checks-while-restoring-a-dump/75635#75635) in 9.1 and updates in 9.2. Here is a related blog with a good write-up: http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/11/postgres-alter-column-problems-and.html

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter wouldn't using `char_length()` slightly better then `length()`?

Comment: @dezso: Both do exactly the same. The only difference: there are variants of `length()` for other data types.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter apparently, my mind somehow mixed in the `bit_length()` function and `length(string bytea, encoding name )`, too - all into one nonexistent function.

Answer (score 10):

From the page that you linked to:

> "There is no performance difference among these three types, apart
>   from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a
>   few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a
>   length-constrained column. While character(n) has performance
>   advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage
>   in PostgreSQL; in fact character(n) is usually the slowest of the
>   three because of its additional storage costs. In most situations text
>   or character varying should be used instead."

There doesn't seem to be any drawbacks of using the `text` data type in Postgres.

However, you should consider if you really want to allow huge texts to be stored in the database. Keeping it as a `varchar` but with a higher limit would protect you from inadvertently storing vast amounts of data in the database.

Comment: So would using a `CHECK` constraint?

Comment: @Vérace As of [v9.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/release-9-2.html#AEN114949:~:text=Increasing%20the%20length%20limit%20for%20a,no%20longer%20requires%20a%20table%20rewrite) I prefer `varchar(n)` over `text` because it allows me to increase the length without rechecking. Changing a check constraint forces a recheck, regardless of whether you're increasing the char length. That check uses an AccessExclusiveLock, preventing reads, making it non-ideal for production dbs.

Answer (score 6):

All the datatypes you mention use the same internal representation (moderately famous `struct varlena`)

The `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` datatypes just add length checks to this, and (in case of `CHAR`), have different space-padding semantics.

You can use `TEXT` safely wherever nothing of above is important to your logic.