# Import data from Excel to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, excel, postgresql

I have seen questions on stackoverflow similar/same as the one I am asking now, however I couldn't manage to solve it in my situation.

Here is the thing:
I have an excel spreadsheet(.xlsx) whom i converted in comma seperated value(.CSV) as it is said in some answers:

My excel file looks something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------
name  |  surname | voteNo  | VoteA | VoteB | VoteC
--------------------------------------------------
john  |  smith   | 1001    | 30    | 154   | 25
--------------------------------------------------
anothe|  person  | 1002    | 430   | 34    | 234
--------------------------------------------------
other |  one     | 1003    | 35    | 154   | 24
--------------------------------------------------
john  |  smith   | 1004    | 123   | 234   | 53
--------------------------------------------------
john  |  smith   | 1005    | 23    | 233   | 234
--------------------------------------------------
```

In PostgreSQL I created a table with name `allfields` and created 6 columns
1st and 2nd one as a character[] and last 4 ones as integers with the same name as shown in the excel table `(name, surname, voteno, votea, voteb, votec)`

Now I'm doing this:

```
copy allfields from 'C:\Filepath\filename.csv';
```

But I'm getting this error:

> ```
> could not open file "C:\Filepath\filename.csv" for reading: Permission denied
> SQL state: 42501
> ```

#### My questions are:

1. Should I create those columns in `allfields` table in PostgreSQL?
2. Do I have to modify anything else in Excel file?
3. And why I get this 'permission denied' error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the Problem was that i need to change the `path` of the `Excel file`. I inserted it in the **public account** where *all users can access it*.

If you face the same problem move your `excel file` to ex `C:\\User\Public` folder (this folder is a public folder without any restrictions), otherwise you have to deal with `Windows permission issues`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Based on your file, neither of the first two columns needs to be an array type (character[]) - unlike C-strings, the "character" type in postgres *is* a string already. You might want to make things easier and use `varchar` as the type of those two columns instead.
2. I don't think you do.
3. Check that you don't still have that file open and locked in excel - if you did a "save as" to convert from xlsx to csv from within excel then you'll likely need to close out the file in excel.

Comment: @yieldsfalsehodd 
I was searching for varchar when creating new column, but there were ne varchar. Anyway i made them 'character' as u suggested. 
However still getting the same error about file permission. The file is closed at all (and yeah i converted to .csv by doing Save As).

Answer (score 1):

**SQL state: 42501** in PostgreSQL means you don't have permission to perform such operation in the intended schema. This [error code list](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/errcodes-appendix.html) shows that.

Check that you're pointing to the correct schema and your user has enough privileges.

[Documentation also states](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html) that you need select privileges on origin table and insert privileges on the destination table.

> You must have select privilege on the table whose values are read by
>   COPY TO, and insert privilege on the table into which values are
>   inserted by COPY FROM. It is sufficient to have column privileges on
>   the column(s) listed in the command.

Comment: I checked all man...User have all the priviledges.
I gave also all public privileges to db, table and columns seperately

again same error !

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes I think you can. For COPY command, there is optional HEADER clause. Check 
   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html
2. I don't think so. With my #1 and #3, it should works.
3. You need superuser permission for that.

Comment: tried smth like:
copy allfields from 'C:\filepath\filename.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER
also user have all the privileges. I created a new role and made it as superuser..

same error !

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Should I create those columns in allfields table in PostgreSQL?

Use [`text`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221) for the character fields. Not an array in any case, as [@yieldsfalsehood pointed out correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21026797/939860).

> 2) Do I have to modify anything else in Excel file?

No.

> 3) And why I get this 'permission denied' error?

The file needs be **accessible to your system user `postgres`** (or what ever user you are running the postgres server with). [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html)

> `COPY` with a file name instructs the PostgreSQL server to directly read
>   from or write to a file. The file must be accessible to the server and
>   the name must be specified from the viewpoint of the server.

The privileges of the database user are not the cause of the problem. However (quoting the same page):

> `COPY` naming a file or command is only allowed to database superusers,
>   since it allows reading or writing any file that the server has privileges to access.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the permission problem, if you are using psql to issue the `COPY` command, try using `\copy` instead.

Comment: What are you using as the front end client to issue the COPY?  Other tools have other ways to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For those who do not wish to move the files they wish to read to a different location(public) for some reason. Here is a clear solution.

1. Right click the folder holding the file and select **properties**.
2. Select the **Security** tab under properties.
3. Select **Edit**
4. Select **Add**
5. Under the field *Enter the object Names to select*, Type in **Everyone**
6. Click **OK** to all the dialog boxes or **Apply** if it is activated
7. Try reading the file again.