# Inner join performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, database-design, postgresql-performance

I have a table that has a lot of foreign keys that I will need to inner join so I can search. There might be upwards of 10 of them, meaning I'd have to do 10 inner joins. Each of the tables being joined may only be a few rows, compared to the massive (millions of rows) table that I am joining them with.

I just need to know if the joins are a fast way (using only Postgres) to do this, or if there might be a more clever way I can do it using subqueries or something.

Here is some made up data as an example:

```
create table a (
   a_id serial primary key,
   name character varying(32)
);
create table b (
   b_id serial primary key,
   name character varying(32)
);

--just 2 tables for simplicity, but i really need like 10 or more

create table big_table (
   big_id serial primary key,
   a_id int references a(a_id),
   b_id int references b(b_id)
);

--filter big_table based on the name column of a and b
--big_table only contains fks to a and b, so in this example im using
--left joins so i can compare by the name column
select big_id,a.name,b.name from big_table
  left join a using (a_id)
  left join b using (b_id)
  where (? is null or a.name=?) and (? is null or b.name=?);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the query? Which columns do you *need* in the result? What is the intention behind the `WHERE` clause? Postgres version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, joins are a fast way. Which way might be the fastest depends on the exact requirements. A couple of hints:

- The purpose of your `WHERE` clause is unclear. It seems you intend to join to *all* look-up tables and include a condition for each, while you only actually need some of them. That's inefficient. Rather use [dynamic-sql](/questions/tagged/dynamic-sql) and only include in the query what you actually *need*.
- With the current query, since all of your fk columns in the main table can be `NULL`, you *must* use [**`LEFT JOIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) instead of `JOIN` or you will exclude rows with `NULL` values in the fk columns.
- The `name` columns in the look-up tables should certainly be defined `NOT NULL`. And I would not use the non-descriptive column name `"name"`, that's an unhelpful naming convention. [I also would use `text` instead of `varchar(32)`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

Comment: thanks for the advice! ill edit my question, but here is an explanation:

the where clause was to filter based on some fk references. for instance, i wanted to filter `big_table` based on the name columns of tables `a` and `b`. `big_table` only had fks though, so to filter on the `name` column id need to combine them somehow.

youre right about the left join. that is what i get for writing off the top of my head.

dont worry, theyre not really named `name`. your advice about using a constraint instead of varchar is awesome though. thanks!