# Change column type from varchar to timestamp

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

I have a table that is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE session_requests
(
  id character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  authorization_enc character varying(255),
  auto_close integer,
  date_created character varying(255) DEFAULT '1970-01-01 01:00:00'::character varying,,
....
)
```

I'm trying to do

```
alter table session_requests alter column date_created type timestamp using date_created::timestamp;
```

the error that I'm getting is

```
ERROR:  default for column "date_created" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp
```

Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: You first need to drop/remove the default value. Then you can change the data type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was hoping not to go there... But your suggestion will definitely work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do it in one transaction. You can even do it in a [single statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html):

```
ALTER TABLE session_requests
  ALTER date_created DROP DEFAULT
 ,ALTER date_created type timestamp USING date_created::timestamp
 ,ALTER date_created SET DEFAULT '1970-01-01 01:00:00'::timestamp;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2639c/1)

Aside: `character varying(255)` is almost always a bad (pointless) choice in Postgres. More:

- [Refactor foreign key to fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558650/refactor-foreign-key-to-fields/24560486?s=1|0.2537#24560486)

Comment: Sorry, but can you elaborate on why `CHARACTER VARYING` is a bad choice for a column data type?

Comment: `varchar(255)` in particular. Follow the link.