# Postgres UPDATE statement doesn't update any rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have two tables:

`"TABLE1"`

```
"Id" integer,
"unit" varchar(255)
...
```

`"TABLE2"`

```
"Id" integer,
"Description" varchar(250)
...
```

`TABLE1` is a descendant of `TABLE2` - in Postgres parlance, it "inherits" from `TABLE2`.

`TABLE2` has rows with a matching "Id" for every row in `TABLE1`.  It also has many other descendants and there are many more rows in `TABLE2` than in `TABLE1`.

For reasons not pertinent here, I need to copy the text from `TABLE1."unit"` into `TABLE2."Description"` for all rows where the `Id` column is the same.

The following query succeeds, but doesn't update any rows:

```
UPDATE  ONLY public."TABLE2" as t2
SET    ("Description") = (t1."unit"::regclass)
FROM   "TABLE1" as t1
WHERE  t1."Id" = t2."Id";
```

I tried the query without `ONLY`, but it failed with a "name" error.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are mixing double-quoted identifiers and unquoted ones, but this has relevance in Postgres. What is a `"name" error`? Please provide the verbatim error message. ***[Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32380510/edit)*** your question to provide a *complete and verbatim* table definition for `"TABLE1"` and `"TABLE2"` (what you get in psql with `\d tbl`) to give us a fighting chance. Add any triggers (and the used trigger function), rules or indexes there may be. And *always* your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE ONLY public."TABLE2" t2
SET    "Description" = t1."unit" -- ::regclass  -- ???
FROM   public."TABLE1" t1
WHERE  t1."Id" = t2."Id";
```

Are you sure that `"TABLE1"` inherits from `"TABLE2"`? The names would indicate the opposite.

Why would you cast to `regclass` when the target is `varchar` as well? Do you understand the data type [`regclass`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html)?

A cast to `regclass` fails with an exception if the string is not a valid table (or related) object. In Postgres 9.4 or later you might use the function `to_regclass()` instead that returns NULL for illegal identifiers:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

I removed the cast.

Why do you use `varchar(255)` for `"Table1".unit` and `varchar(250)` for "Table2"."Description"? Why use `varchar(255)` to begin with? It typically indicates that the Postgres data type `varchar` has not been understood:

- [Refactor foreign key to fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558650/refactor-foreign-key-to-fields/24560486#24560486)

Why would you schema-qualify `public."TABLE2"`, but not `"TABLE1"` in your query?
Why do you use those tedious double-quoted mixed-case identifiers to begin with?

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

The error code `P0001` you mentioned [in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380510/postgres-update-statement-doesnt-update-any-rows/32386149#comment52633991_32380862) is a PL/pgSQL error. [The documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/errcodes-appendix.html)

```
Class P0 — PL/pgSQL Error
P0000   plpgsql_error
P0001   raise_exception
```

There might be one or more trigger functions on `"TABLE2"`, which you forgot to mention.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
UPDATE  t2
SET    "Description" = t1."unit"
FROM   "TABLE1" as t1
JOIN   "TABLE2" AS t2 ON t1."Id" = t2."Id";
```

If there is a chance that the unit field will reach 255, you may get a truncation error on update to table 2.

In this case you can review your field to find out the offending row:

```
SELECT t1."unit", LEN(t1."unit")
FROM   "TABLE1" as t1
WHERE LEN(t1."unit") > 250
```

AND/OR Update the field, taking the left 250 characters

```
UPDATE  t2
SET    "Description" = LEFT(t1."unit", 250)
FROM   "TABLE1" as t1
JOIN   "TABLE2" AS t2 ON t1."Id" = t2."Id";
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  Unfortunately, I still don't have a working solution -- the query ran for over an hour, then crapped out with an error:    ERROR:  CM_FORBIDDEN_OPERATION
********** Error **********

ERROR: CM_FORBIDDEN_OPERATION
SQL state: P0001

Comment: You completely ignore the mentioned *inheritance*. What's more, the suggested `UPDATE` statements are plain invalid in Postgres. [Please consult the manual for basics before you write more misleading answers.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html)