# Count the most recent number of consecutive rows with a null value

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I'm doing some data analysis in PostgreSQL 10.6, based on this demo setup:

```
create table history (
    registered_unix int,
    requested_unix int,
    alias character varying(255)
);

INSERT INTO history VALUES
  (1537841388, 1537878224, '3')
, (1538093202, 1538095740, '1')
, (1538093186, 1538095740, '3')
, (1538105501, 1538107039, '2')
, (1538105501, 1538107039, '4')
, (1538205007, 1538242243, '2')
, (1538205012, NULL      , '1')
, (1538105501, NULL      , '1')
, (1538205007, NULL      , '3')
, (1538105501, NULL      , '3')
, (1538040863, NULL      , '3')
, (1537985996, NULL      , '3')
, (1538205007, NULL      , '4')
, (1538093186, NULL      , '4')
, (1538205301, NULL      , '5')
, (1538105501, NULL      , '5')
, (1538093186, NULL      , '5');
```

I'm trying to count the number of consecutive `alias` rows where `requested_unix` is null, but only for the first occurrence and where the consecutive occurrences are greater or equal to 2.

The data is **sorted by alias, then registered_unix DESC**:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Alias 1: Included b/c its 2 most recent "requested_unix" values are null.

Alias 2: Skipped. Requested unix has a value on its most recent row

Alias 3: Included b/c its 2 most recent "requested_unix" values are null.  The older ones are discarded.

Alias 4: Skipped. Only has 1 most recent "requested_unix" value with null.  2nd row has a value.

Alias 5: Included. 3 consecutive most recent values are null.

There are all kind of tickets with counting consecutive occurrences or finding the first occurrence, but it seems I want to combine the two approaches.

Comment: Thanks for having such good example data to work from. I set up a dbfiddle for folks to use. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0fb19ab6278acd9f5bf9bef3f6a73ea2

Comment: Well that is cool.  Didn't know fiddles had come to databases.

Comment: Please always disclose your version of Postgres.

Comment: Aside: `character varying(255)`? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24560486/939860

Comment: Thanks for the update!  Probably just habit for any text field I come across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DISTINCT ON`, we only need a single subquery:

```
SELECT alias
     , CASE WHEN requested_unix IS NULL THEN ct   ELSE rn - 1          END AS missed
     , CASE WHEN requested_unix IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE registered_unix END AS last_success
     , most_recent
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (alias)
          *
        , row_number()         OVER (PARTITION BY alias ORDER BY registered_unix DESC) AS rn
        , count(*)             OVER (PARTITION BY alias) AS ct
        , max(registered_unix) OVER (PARTITION BY alias) AS most_recent
   FROM   history h
   ORDER  BY alias, requested_unix IS NULL, registered_unix DESC
   ) latest_success
WHERE (requested_unix IS NULL OR rn > 2);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ea421c571f9df44ad7824599fbbd3840)*

In the subquery, retrieve a single row per `alias` with `DISTINCT ON (alias)`. `ORDER BY` makes it the one we need.

- The 1st ORDER-BY item `alias` must agree with `DISTINCT ON`.
- The 2nd ORDER-BY item `requested_unix IS NULL` sorts notnull values on top. (`FALSE` sorts before `TRUE`.) `requested_unix IS NOT NULL DESC` might be more intuitive, but I prefer short code.
- The 3rd ORDER-BY item `registered_unix DESC` picks the *latest* row among those.

Add row number (`rn`), row count (`ct`), and the most recent `registered_unix` (`most_recent`) per partition with window functions (processed before `DISTINCT ON`), and you have all information necessary in a single query level. The outer `SELECT` is just to assemble the requested result format.

Related:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Sorting null values after all others, except special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891803/sorting-null-values-after-all-others-except-special/21892611#21892611)
- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)

Comment: you're amazing.  Thank you.