# How to insert first character of one column into another column?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, sql-view

I have a table with more than 30.000 entries and have to add a new column (`zip_prefixes`) containing the first digit of the a zip code (`zcta`).

I created the column successfully:

```
alter table zeta add column zip_prefixes text;
```

Then I tried to put the values in the column with:

```
update zeta
set zip_prefixes = (
     select substr(cast (zctea as text)1,1) 
     from zeta)
     )
```

Of course I got:

> ```
> error more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
> ```

How can I get the first digit of the value from `zctea` into column `zip_prefixes` of the same row?

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 3):

No need for sub-select:

```
update zeta
  set zip_prefixes = substr(zctea, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

update zeta
set zip_prefixes = substr(zctea as text)1,1) 
   There is no need for select query and casting

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider ***not*** adding a functionally dependent column. It's typically cleaner and cheaper overall to retrieve the first character on the fly. If you *need* a "table", I suggest to add a [**`VIEW`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html).
2. Why the need to `cast(zctea as text)`? A zip code should be `text` to begin with.
3. Name it `zip_prefix`, not <strike>`zip_prefixes`</strike>.
4. Use the simpler and cheaper `left()`:

```
CREATE VIEW zeta_plus AS
SELECT *, left(zctea::text, 1) AS zip_prefix FROM zeta;  -- or without cast?
```

---

***If*** you *need* the additional column in the table and the first character is guaranteed to be an ASCII character, consider the data type "char" (with double quotes). 1 byte instead of 2 (on disk) or 5 (in RAM). Details:

- [What is the overhead for varchar(n)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125499/what-is-the-overhead-for-varcharn/125526#125526)
- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

And run both commands in one transaction if you need to minimize lock time and / or avoid a visible column with missing values in the meantime. Faster, too.

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE zeta ADD COLUMN zip_prefix "char";
UPDATE zeta SET zip_prefixes = left(zctea::text, 1);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: OK, thank you very much. Your answers helped a great deal.