# PostgreSQL ERROR: relation does not exist on INSERT Statement

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

I am trying to have my code INSERT a row into my table called `thoughtentries`.  It is in the `public` schema.  I am able to run ths command while connected to my database using `psql`:

`INSERT INTO thoughtentries VALUES('12/17/2016 14:10', 'hi');`

The first column is of `character` type with length 17.  The second column is of type `text`.

When I have my code attempt to INSERT using the same command above I get the error in my log:

`ERROR:  relation "thoughtentries" does not exist at character 13`
`STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO thoughtentries VALUES('12/17/2016 14:11', 'hi');`

I am using `pg` and `pg-format` to format the command. Here is my code to do this:

```
client.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err
  app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
  })
  var textToDB = format('INSERT INTO thoughtentries VALUES(%s, %s);', timestamp, "'hi'")
  client.query(textToDB, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(result)
    client.end(function (err) {
      if (err) throw err
    })
  })
})
```

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you verified that the table was, in fact, created in the `public` schema?

```
SELECT *
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  table_name = 'thoughtentries';
```

Once you have verified that, I see two possible explanations remaining:

1. You are connecting to a different database by mistake. Verify, in the same session, with:

   ```
   select current_database();
   ```
2. Your `search_path` setting does not include the `public` schema. If that's the case, you can schema-qualify the table to fix: `public.thoughtentries`

   - [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Aside: Save timestamps as data type `timestamp`, not `character(17)`.
Actually, don't use `character(n)` at all:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)