# Pros and Cons of Storing Values with Numeric or String Data Types

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

Let's say I am using a Postgres database.

I have numbers stored in one column. I had this column saved as a "text" data type.

If I do not plan on doing any sort of calculation, what would be the benefits of saving it as a numeric data type as far as performance goes?

We have approximately 150 million records.

Comment: There is already a question about text here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings
If you use numeric types, please see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html for the storage requirements. If you really never ever do calculations, it is easy to calculate the different storage requirements now.

Comment: @Arminius Maybe I am missing something, but that does not answer my question. It does not talk about the advantages or disadvantages of storing a number as string vs some numeric data type.

Comment: **Never** store numbers in a `text` column. Apart from the fact that an `integer` column won't let you store invalid numbers it's also more space efficient and faster when comparing values

Comment: Turn your question around - why *would* you store numbers as text??