# Postgres \copy a file with double quotes

Tags: postgresql

This is what my data looks like -

```
"to_claim_id"   "NEW_PATIENT"        "from_rend"     "from_bill"     "to_rend"       "to_bill"       "from_date"     "to_date"       "days_diff"
"10193136348200818391"  "102657"    "103325"    "174597"    "1830139"    "17497"    20180904        20181002        28
```

How do I import this data into my database using `\copy`?

I have tried `\copy public.data from '/data/test' with delimiter E'\t' csv header quote '"'` but I get `ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(25)` error.

Answer (score 0):

That means at least one column in the target table `public.data` is type `varchar(25)` and a corresponding value in the CSV file has more characters.

You might change the data type of such columns (temporarily) to just `varchar` or `text`, import, and then identify and trim offending values - or just live happily ever after as you probably don't need that restriction to begin with.

Related:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)