# Can't execute function created in pgAdmin on sql shell: "function ... does not exist"

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

Below is the error I got:

```
postgres=# select bcount('Deccan');
ERROR:  function bcount(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: select bcount('Deccan');
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Below is my program in pgAdmin:

```sql
create function bcount(brname char(30)) returns int as $$
declare
total_no int;
begin
select count(cno) into total_no from Branch,Ternary where Branch.bid=Ternary.bid and br_name=brname;
return total_no;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

Comment: Use `text` instead of `char(30)` as the parameter type. In fat `char` should never be used.

Comment: I have changed the data type to 'Text' but still it's not working.

Comment: Are the function definition and select execution done with the same database selected?

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

`char(30)` is typically not useful as has been commented. See:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

But that's not the problem.
A different role or missing privileges could also not be the problem, that would produce a different error message.

Your call:

```
select bcount('Deccan');
```

... with an untyped string constant as parameter would be coerced to the type, as long as *any* function of that name is found in the **`search_path`**.

Speaking of which, what was the `search_path` in your pgAdmin environment? Put differently, what's the **schema** your function was created in? Check with:

```sql
SELECT pronamespace::regnamespace AS schema, proname
     , pg_get_functiondef(oid)
FROM   pg_proc
WHERE  proname = 'bcount';
```

And what's the `search_path` in your psql environment? Is the schema of the function contained?

```
SHOW search_path;
```

See:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

It's either that, or you connected to the wrong **database**. A Postgres database cluster consists of any number of databases. If you don't connect to a particular one, you may end up in the default maintenance database named "postgres". In psql, switch with:

```
\c my_database
```

Or you connected to the wrong db cluster altogether.