# Constraint not working as desired for my INSERT?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, sql-insert

I am creating a Table named "Cliente" with some constraints on it as it follows:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Cliente" (
    "K_CODCLIENTE" numeric(5) NOT NULL,
    "N_NOMBRE1" varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    "N_NOMBRE2" varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    "N_APELLIDO1" varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    "N_APELLIDO2" varchar(15),
    "N_DIRECCION" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "Q_TELEFONO" numeric(10) NOT NULL,
    "K_CODREF" numeric(5),
    "I_TIPOID" varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    "Q_IDENTIFICACION" varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Cliente" PRIMARY KEY ("K_CODCLIENTE"),
    CONSTRAINT "UQ_ID_TIPOID_CLIENTE" UNIQUE ("I_TIPOID","Q_IDENTIFICACION"),
    CONSTRAINT "CK_CODCLIENTE" CHECK ("K_CODCLIENTE" >= 100),
    CONSTRAINT "CK_Q_IDENTIFICACION" CHECK ("Q_IDENTIFICACION" IN ('CC', 'PA', 'CE', 'NI', 'OT'))
);
```

When I try to insert some values on it:

```
INSERT INTO "Cliente"
VALUES ('101','Juan','Felipe','Ortiz','Rojas','AK 15 no. 28-05','3101125507',null,'CC','51111111');
```

I get the following error (in PostgreSQL 14, on Fedora):

```
[23514] ERROR: new row for relation "Cliente" violates check constraint "CK_Q_IDENTIFICACION"  
Detail: Failing row contains (101, Juan, Felipe, Ortiz, Rojas, AK 15 no. 28-05, 3101125507, null, CC, 51111111).
```

I am trying to restrict the "Q_IDENTIFICACION" column so it can only be filled with 'CC', 'PA', 'CE, 'NI' or 'OT'.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong when declaring the constraint "CK_Q_IDENTIFICACION"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you messed up the mapping of values and are trying to insert '51111111' to `"Q_IDENTIFICACION"`.

Consider this more revealing variant with a formatted list of target columns:

```sql
INSERT INTO "Cliente"
       ("K_CODCLIENTE", "N_NOMBRE1", "N_NOMBRE2", "N_APELLIDO1", "N_APELLIDO2", "N_DIRECCION"    , "Q_TELEFONO", "K_CODREF", "I_TIPOID", "Q_IDENTIFICACION")
VALUES ('101'         , 'Juan'     ,'Felipe'    , 'Ortiz'      , 'Rojas'      , 'AK 15 no. 28-05', '3101125507', NULL      , 'CC'      , '51111111');       -- !
```

Maybe you want to switch the last two column names in the table definition - and (not) adapt the `VALUES` list in the `INSERT` accordingly? (`varchar(2)` vs. `varchar(10)` seems switched as well.)

For persisted code, it's generally advisable to spell out target columns in an `INSERT` command in any case.

Asides:

Reconsider all these pesky double-quoted upper case identifiers. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Consider plain type `text` instead of `varchar(n)` with strikingly tight character limits. See:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

Comment: Thanks but it did not work. I still get the [23514] ERROR using that `INSERT`.

Comment: In regards of the double-quoted upper case identifiers, the script was generated by pgmodeler. I'm not really sure why it generated it like that. I usually use lower case identifiers when working in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I did not fix the order of columns. Just spelled it out for you to see. I am unable to tell how it *should* be. Possibly switch the last two values, or the last two column names in the table definition? Added a bit above.

Comment: Sir Erwin, I have to ask one MCQ question from you about SQL is **What is the meaning of "GROUP BY" clause in MySQL?**  and the options are :  `(a) Group data by column values`  `(b) Group data by column and row values`  `(c) Group data by row values`  `(d) None of the above`  which option is correct here?