Fetching unexpected results from WHRE clause with bpchar and character varying fields
I am new to PostgreSQL.
In my Postgres 14.8 database I have a students table. When executing the query:
SELECT stud_id, batch_type, subject, jdate ,subj_id, sdtime, subj_hours
FROM studs 
ORDER BY jdate DESC, subject DESC, stud_id ASC
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0

I get the following correct result as expected:



Stud_id bpchar
Batch_type Character varying
Subject Character varying
Jdate date
Subj_id integer
Sdtime Timestamp without time zone
Subj_hours integer




3591f1gff960h09l
Residential
Software Systems Development 7
null
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
10


983e292ce1xy69c0
Residential
Software Systems Development 5
null
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
14


7k992ad576842507
Residential
Software Systems Development 4
null
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
12


b9ahibji8jgaeth2
Residential
Software Systems Development 3
null
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
10


5758uh95376eb0b4
Residential
Software Systems Development 2
2024-03-20
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
12


6ch9b2f7894740er
Residential
Software Systems Development
2024-03-20
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
14


a877450586v3869h
Residential
Software Systems Development
2024-03-20
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
14


78635a8s1586d95c
Residential
Software Systems Development
2024-03-15
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
14


b58c7fbf57328468
Residential
Software Systems Development
2024-03-15
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
16


acb8g94351e84226
Residential
Software Systems Development
2024-02-25
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
15


fvhud7653fd85m1s
Residential
Software Systems Development
2024-02-20
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
16


b7hf962ffb6he96j
Residential
Design and Technology
2024-02-19
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
14


394ij84275c6e97d
Residential
Software Systems Development
2024-01-15
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
16



The stud_id is char and subject is character varying. Basically I wanted to list all the rows  where stud_id is greater than '983e292ce1xy69c0' with subject 'Software Systems Development 5'.Since subject is ordered DESC, stud_id ASC, I added the following Where condition to the query.
But by adding WHERE condition in the query as below:
SELECT stud_id, batch_type, subject, jdate ,subj_id, sdtime, subj_hours form studs
WHERE subject < 'Software Systems Development 5'
AND stud_id > '983e292ce1xy69c0'
ORDER BY jdate DESC, subject DESC, stud_id ASC
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0

I get erroneous result as follows:



Stud_id bpchar
Batch_type Character varying
Subject Character varying
Jdate date
Subj_id integer
Sdtime Timestamp without   time zone
Subj_hours integer




b9ahibji8jgaeth2
Residential
Software   Systems Development 3
null
35
2024-03-20   12:42:55.040189
10


a877450586v3869h
Residential
Software   Systems Development
2024-03-20
35
2024-03-20   12:42:55.040189
14


b58c7fbf57328468
Residential
Software   Systems Development
2024-03-15
35
2024-03-20   12:42:55.040189
16


acb8g94351e84226
Residential
Software   Systems Development
2024-02-25
35
2024-03-20   12:42:55.040189
15


fvhud7653fd85m1s
Residential
Software   Systems Development
2024-02-20
35
2024-03-20   12:42:55.040189
16


b7hf962ffb6he96j
Residential
Design and   Technology
2024-02-19
35
2024-03-20   12:42:55.040189
14



but I was expecting the following result:



Stud_id bpchar
Batch_type Character varying
Subject Character varying
Jdate date
Subj_id integer
Sdtime Timestamp without time zone
Subj_hours integer




7k992ad576842507
Residential
Software Systems Development 4
null
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
12


b9ahibji8jgaeth2
Residential
Software Systems Development 3
null
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
10


5758uh95376eb0b4
Residential
Software Systems Development 2
2024-03-20
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
12


6ch9b2f7894740er
Residential
Software Systems Development
2024-03-20
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
14


a877450586v3869h
Residential
Software Systems Development
2024-03-20
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
14


78635a8s1586d95c
Residential
Software Systems Development
2024-03-15
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
14


b58c7fbf57328468
Residential
Software Systems Development
2024-03-15
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
16


acb8g94351e84226
Residential
Software Systems Development
2024-02-25
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
15


fvhud7653fd85m1s
Residential
Software Systems Development
2024-02-20
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
16


b7hf962ffb6he96j
Residential
Design and Technology
2024-02-19
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
14


394ij84275c6e97d
Residential
Software Systems Development
2024-01-15
35
2024-03-20 12:42:55.040189
16



Some rows are missed in the result. Can someone help me to understand the reason and how to fix it?

7k992ad576842507 is lexicographically smaller than 983e292ce1xy69c0. It is missing in your result since you have stud_id > '983e292ce1xy69c0'. 394ij84275c6e97d  - the last one - and a few others too.

Please fix the typos in your question, so we can focus on the actual problem. SQL does not accept typographic quotes like ’. I doubt you want leading spaces in your filter ... And always disclose your Postgres version, please.

Not sure about your stud_id values. So also not sure about the appropriate data type. But bpchar is never appropriate. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/939860

Hi @ErwinBrandstetter,  Thank you for your reply. Apologies for the typo. I have corrected it now.  The postgres version is 14.8 please.

Hi @ Erwin Brandstetter, Thank you for your response. The table is old and existing.  Not sure about the reason for choosing bpchar.

Tell us (in the question) about the nature of stud_id values, and what stud_id > '983e292ce1xy69c0' is supposed to achieve exactly.

Hi @Stefanov.sm, Thanks for your response. Sorry,  I am still confused If 7k992ad576842507 is lexicographically smaller than 983e292ce1xy69c0, then why how did 7k992ad576842507  was listed below 983e292ce1xy69c0 in the first result  (the result for query without where clause). Can you please suggest me how to solve this please?

@ Erwin Brandstetter, I have added the required info in the question now . Hope this helps. Thank you.

join_date and jdate seem to be the same, just messed up in the question?

@ErwinBrandstetter yes please. Sorry corrected it now.

About "how did 7k992ad576842507 appear below 983e292ce1xy69c0" pls. see this SO thread. It explains things clearly.

Keyset pagination with ROW value comparison
It seems you want rows starting from the 4th row in the first result. A typical use case for "keyset pagination". See:

SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'

However, your sort order is dictated by:
ORDER BY join_date DESC, subject DESC, stud_id ASC

Two issues prevent a simple solution with ROW value comparison:

jdate has null values.
A mix of opposing sort orders (ASC and DESC). See:

Enforcing index scan for multicolumn comparison



Without these issues, this would work:
SELECT ...
FROM   studs
WHERE  (jdate, subject, stud_id)
     < ('2024-03-20', 'Software Systems Development 5', '983e292ce1xy69c0')
ORDER  BY jdate DESC, subject DESC, stud_id DESC  -- adapted !!
LIMIT  15;

Very fast with a unique (!) index on studs(jdate, subject, stud_id).
While there are null values:
Are you aware that unique indices with null values are possible since Postgres 15?

Create unique constraint with null columns

Are you aware of the NULLS LAST clause?

Sort NULL values to the end of a table

But ROW value comparison still fails with any null values.
Solution for your quandary
Stuck with your unfortunate setup, only (comparatively) slow and tedious workarounds remain. For your original sort order:
ORDER  BY jdate DESC, subject DESC, stud_id ASC

Fork cases
To make the best of it, fork 2 cases based on filter values:

Filter value for $jdate is NULL

WHERE subject < $subject
OR    subject = $subject AND stud_id > $stud_id


Filter value for $jdate is NOT NULL

Use partial ROW value comparison for the two leading columns:
WHERE (jdate, subject) < ($jdate, $subject)
OR    (jdate, subject) = ($jdate, $subject) AND stud_id > $stud_id

Support that with an index on studs(jdate, subject). And, possibly, another on studs(subject). If there are not too many dupes it will still be fast. See:

PostgreSQL index not used for query on IP ranges

Combined solution (not recommended)
You can combine both into a single query, but that will be slower for all.
WHERE CASE WHEN $jdate IS NULL
           THEN         subject  <          $subject
             OR         subject  =          $subject  AND stud_id > $stud_id
           ELSE (jdate, subject) < ($jdate, $subject)
             OR (jdate, subject) = ($jdate, $subject) AND stud_id > $stud_id
      END

I formatted to (hopefully) make the case clear.
We don't require additional parentheses because operator precedence works in out favor. (AND binds before OR)
My advice
Fix null values and set the column jdate to NOT NULL.
And sort by stud_id DESC.
Or find some way to create a multicolumn expression index with an inverted stud_id value. (Should be possible if the value is of numeric nature.) And use a matching query. Find an example here:

Optimize query with OFFSET on large table


@qquest It may be a tough problem. The hardest part for me, though, was to determine what the question is about. Learn to ask clear questions, and you will get great answers.

Thank you @Erwin Brandstetter. Apologies for not making my question clearer to you.   Yes unfortunately the table is very old. The jdate contains lot of Null values. As jdate is in DESC order the NULLS are at the top which is as expected. As I see the NULL at the end when its in ASC order.    The query provided by you helps get the right rows in this subset of values I have provided.  Thank you. Is there a way I can handle situation both when jdate is 'Null' or 'Not Null' please?

@qquest: I added a solution for your quandary.

Thank you @Erwin Brandstetter.  Cant we have a single query which checks if the value for jdate is NULL or not NULL and retrieve the results please?

@qquest: I added a combined solution. (I wouldn't use it.) And I fixed some issues.
